# Why does keyword "this" not work on jQuery removeClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can use `this` to get the id from my clicked button, but I cannot select the clicked button with `this` to run my setTimeout function.

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
      var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
      $(this).addClass("pressed");
      setTimeout(function() {$(this).removeClass("pressed");} , 100);
    })
```

However, I can run it in this way by not using `this`:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
  var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
  $(this).addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function() {$("#" + userChosenColour).removeClass("pressed");} , 100);
})
```

Do I have any misconception on the keyword `this`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` keyword is quite different from other languages... I recommend [this & object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) to know more.

For your problem, one simple and recommended solution would be:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this) // Store the jQuery object and use it everywhere
  var userChosenColour = $this.attr("id");
  $this.addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function() {$this.removeClass("pressed");} , 100);
})
```